# How to merge multiple table row if the item is exist using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have problem where I need to merge or distinct my table row if the item is exist and same item. I'm currently use Jquery and laravel. right now I have function where every time I click the table row it will append to another table. to understand well, I will share to you my sample function that I already created and some images.

Expected Output:
[image: expected output]

Table (1)

```
<table id="product_category" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Item Pts</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($product_table as $product_data)
            <tr class="product_details">
                <td class="item_code">{{$product_data->item_code}}</td>
                <td class="item_name">{{$product_data->item_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$product_data->item_points}}</td>
                <td>{{$product_data->item_qty}}</td>
                <td>{{$product_data->item_price}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table (2)

```
<table class="table append_product_tbody">
<thead >
    <tr >
        <th style="font-size:12px;">Item Code</th>
        <th style="font-size:12px;">Item</th>
        <th style="font-size:12px;">Item Pts</th>
        <th style="font-size:12px;">Qty</th>
        <th style="font-size:12px;">Price</th>
        <th style="font-size:12px;">Total Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="append_tbody_validation"></tbody>
```

Here is my function:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    //submit button

    if($('.total_amount').val() == '0.00' || $('.amount_change').val() == '0.00') {
        $('.process_transaction').prop( "disabled", true );
    }

    orderProcessOption();

    var i = 0;
    $('#product_category td').click(function(){

        i++;

        var item_code = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text();
        var item_pts = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
        var item_qty = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').text();
        var item_price = item_qty != '0' ? $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text() : '0';

        var append_product_process;
        append_product_process = '<tr style="text-align:center;" id="row_added_item'+l+'">\
        <td>'+item_code+'</td>\
        <td>'+item+'</td>\
        <td>'+item_pts+'</td>\
        <td><input type="number" value="1" '+(item_qty === '0' ? 'disabled' : '')+' class="form-control onchange_product_qty"></td>\
        <td class="append_item_price">'+parseFloat(item_price).toFixed(2)+'</td>\
        <td style="border:none;" class="final_price">'+parseFloat(item_price).toFixed(2)+'</td>\
        <td><center><i class="far fa-trash-alt btn_remove_added_item" id="'+l+'"></i></center></td>\
        </tr>';

        $('tbody.append_tbody_validation').append(append_product_process);

        productChangeQty();

        $('.btn_remove_added_item').click(function(){
            var button_id_option_two = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#row_added_item'+button_id_option_two).remove();
            orderProcessOption();
        });

        //order process
        var radioOrderProcessValue = $("input[name='order_process_opt']:checked").val();
        if(radioOrderProcessValue == 'shipping'){
            var sum = 0;
            $('.final_price').each(function(x,y){
                sum += parseInt($(this).text());                                   
            })           
            $('.total_amount').val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));   
        }

        orderProcessOption();

    });

});
```

Onchange Quantity:

```
    function productChangeQty(){
    $('.onchange_product_qty').on('change',function(){

        var number_qty_update = $(this).val();
        var final_price_update = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(5)').text();
        var append_item_price = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text();
        var convert_item_price = parseFloat(append_item_price).toFixed(2);
        var convert_final_price_to_int = parseFloat(final_price_update).toFixed(2);

        var computation_final_price = convert_item_price * number_qty_update;

        console.log(computation_final_price);

        var new_final_price_to_fixed = parseFloat(computation_final_price).toFixed(2);

        $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(5)').text(new_final_price_to_fixed);


        orderProcessOption();

    });

}
```

Output:

[image: Function Output]

Comment: please provide a demo code with html .

Comment: yah. sure thanks for the info

Comment: please see the new update thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new row, put the $product->item_code as a CLASS value on your .

```
var append_product_process;
append_product_process = '<tr style="text-align:center;" id="row_added_item' + l + '" class="'+item_code+'">
```

Then, put a IF around it and check if any of the  element of your table already have the class with the upcoming $product->item_code.

```
$("tbody.append_tbody_validation > tr").each(function () {

    if ($(this).hasClass(item_code)){
        //find the input qty element inside $(this) and add 1;
    }else{
        append_product_process = '<tr style="text-align:center;" id="row_added_item' + l + '" class="' + item_code + '">...
    }
});
```

I've just write it down end probably wont work as it is, but you should try this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `item code` if that code is already exist in table do not append new row but get the `quantity` and `price` and put new values to same td.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //submit button

  if ($('.total_amount').val() == '0.00' || $('.amount_change').val() == '0.00') {
    $('.process_transaction').prop("disabled", true);
  }

  //orderProcessOption();

  var i = 0;
  $('#product_category td').click(function() {
    var is_there = true;
    i++;

    var item_code = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
    //looping through trsto find matching item code 
    $(".append_tbody_validation tr td:contains('" + item_code + "')").each(function() {
      //getting quanity
      var item_qty = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(3) input").val();
      var new_qty = Number(item_qty) + 1;
      //put new value in quantity
      $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(3) input").val(new_qty)
      //getting final price
      var item_price = $(this).closest("tr").find('td.final_price').text();
      //appending new price
      $(this).closest("tr").find('td.final_price').text(item_price * new_qty)
      is_there = false;
    });
    var item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var item_pts = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var item_qty = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(3)').text();
    var item_price = item_qty != '0' ? $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text() : '0';
    //if true 
    if (is_there) {
      ///append new row
      var append_product_process;
      append_product_process = '<tr style="text-align:center;" id="row_added_item' + i + '">\
        <td>' + item_code + '</td>\
        <td>' + item + '</td>\
        <td>' + item_pts + '</td>\
        <td><input type="number" value="1" ' + (item_qty === '0' ? 'disabled' : '') + ' class="form-control onchange_product_qty"></td>\
        <td class="append_item_price">' + parseFloat(item_price).toFixed(2) + '</td>\
        <td style="border:none;" class="final_price">' + parseFloat(item_price).toFixed(2) + '</td>\
        <td><center><i class="far fa-trash-alt btn_remove_added_item" id="' + i + '"></i></center></td>\
        </tr>';

      $('tbody.append_tbody_validation').append(append_product_process);
    }
    //productChangeQty();

    $('.btn_remove_added_item').click(function() {
      var button_id_option_two = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#row_added_item' + button_id_option_two).remove();
      //orderProcessOption();
    });

    //order process
    var radioOrderProcessValue = $("input[name='order_process_opt']:checked").val();
    if (radioOrderProcessValue == 'shipping') {
      var sum = 0;
      $('.final_price').each(function(x, y) {
        sum += parseInt($(this).text());
      })
      $('.total_amount').val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));
    }

    // orderProcessOption();

  });
  $(document).on('change', ".onchange_product_qty", function() {

    var number_qty_update = $(this).val();
    var final_price_update = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(5)').text();
    var append_item_price = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text();
    var convert_item_price = parseFloat(append_item_price).toFixed(2);
    var convert_final_price_to_int = parseFloat(final_price_update).toFixed(2);

    var computation_final_price = convert_item_price * number_qty_update;

    //console.log(computation_final_price);

    var new_final_price_to_fixed = parseFloat(computation_final_price).toFixed(2);

    $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(5)').text(new_final_price_to_fixed);


    //orderProcessOption();

  });

});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="product_category" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Code</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Item Pts</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="product_details">
      <td class="item_code">123</td>
      <td class="item_name">Abc</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="product_details">
      <td class="item_code">1234</td>
      <td class="item_name">Abcd</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>47</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table append_product_tbody">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="font-size:12px;">Item Code</th>
      <th style="font-size:12px;">Item</th>
      <th style="font-size:12px;">Item Pts</th>
      <th style="font-size:12px;">Qty</th>
      <th style="font-size:12px;">Price</th>
      <th style="font-size:12px;">Total Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="append_tbody_validation"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: however there is problem on pricing lncorrect computation. right now 45 * 3 =  90 it must be 135

Comment: with which value you need to multiply by quantity to show in final price?

Comment: as you can see. if you try to click the item, it will display, however when you try to click it again. the price is not multiply

Comment: sorry it was my mistake now check :)

Comment: hi swati, there is still problem. if you put number on the qty and reclick the item, it will multiple times the price..

Comment: lets say you want to put quantity 10 and you click the item, it will multiple times the price

Comment: yes because current code is taking quantity from table and then add new quantity to it ? if you don't want user change quantity directly from quantity disable it for user .

Comment: the user allowed to edit the custom number of quantity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215821/discussion-between-swati-and-devge).